# Rails listener Paypal IPN always return INVALID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I've build a listener for my IPN. I can receive the request via IPN Simulator and all the parameters are correct, but when I send it back to [link for sending my request to make validations](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate) it will ALWAYS return INVALID.

I've tried changing the encoding on my PayPal account to UTF-8 but it didn't work.

I'm not using any gem for this and I'm not looking forward to this.

```
 class PaymentNotificationController  [:create] #Otherwise the request from PayPal wouldn't make it to the controller


  def create
    response = validate_IPN_notification(request.raw_post)
    case response
    when "VERIFIED"
      P 'worked'

    when "INVALID"
        p 'did not work'
    else
    end
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/html'
  end


  protected 

  

  def validate_IPN_notification(raw)

    uri = URI.parse('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate')
    #uri = URI.parse('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.open_timeout = 60
    http.read_timeout = 60
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    http.use_ssl = true
    response = http.post(uri.request_uri, raw,
                         'Content-Length' => "#{raw.size}",
                         'User-Agent' => "My custom user agent"
                       ).body
  end
end
```

Please help me, I've been stuck with it all afternoon and can't get it figured out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out to be a Windows problem which I don't know how to fix.

I tried the same thing on my Ubuntu 15 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was? otherwise this helps no one

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `not follow exactly what papal requires`

From [Paypal document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

> Your listener HTTP POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal.
>
> Note This message must contain the same fields, in the same order, as the original IPN from PayPal, all preceded by cmd=_notify-validate. Further, this message must use the same encoding as the original.

So you `validate function` would be:

```
def validate_IPN_notification(ipn_url)
  validate_url = "#{ipn_url}?cmd=_notify-validate"
  # Post validate_url
  ...
end
```

Note that the `ipn_url` is the same url of IPN

Comment: I don't think it would work. As said in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/, I must send the request to the URL i'm currently sending. My raw is the same fields, in the same order, that I've received from PayPal

Comment: Could you check the log, what did you receive and send?